# define subselect for a queryover

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

i'm certain that i'm missing something really obvious here.
what I want to acheive is quite simple-

I'd like one query to load all `User`s without hydrating their `Posts` and `Followers` collections.
In another query, I *do* want to initialize these collections, using **SubSelect**.

using `Fetch(..)` in the second query would issue left joins, which I don't want.
I can define those collections' fetching strategies in the mappings like so (fluently):

```
.Not.LazyLoad()
.Fetch.Subselect()
```

which would cause the second query to run the way I want it to, but then I can't turn off the `.Not.LazyLoad()` for the first query (i've tried `.Fetch(u => u.Posts).Lazy` but that doesn't seem to do anything).

what am I missing?

Comment: I've done loads of study on these subject recently and I think I might help. Is there any particular reason why you want to use  subselect?

Comment: this seems like the best option, performance-wise. each user has many posts, so don't want to get the cartesian product you get with `Join`, and I have many users, so I don't want the N+1 select you get with `Select`.

Comment: There are few tricks to avoid cartesian products. I am going to try and reply with a proper answer.

Comment: It's interesting that if you use a subselect fetch strategy in your mappings, you get the desired behavior IF lazy loading, but using .Eager on a query over still forces you to join. (unlike the criteria API which seems to preserve your mapping preferences when setting fetch mode to eager / select)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I normally set `lazy=true` in my mappings (Ayende [wrote about it](http://ayende.com/blog/4573/nhibernate-is-lazy-just-live-with-it)) cause I prefer to control the behaviors in my code.

Doing so your associations will be hydrated only if you require them.

```
var users = session.QueryOver<User>()
    .List();
```

Will load all your users but won't load their posts, unless you access an element of the collection:

```
var postTitle = users[0].Posts[0].Title;
```

If you want to load some users and their posts you can simply do something like this:

```
Post posts = null;

var users = session.QueryOver<User>()
    .Where(x => x.Name == "Jamie")
    .Inner.JoinAlias(t => t.Posts, () => posts)
    .List();
```

or:

```
Post posts = null;

var users = session.QueryOver<User>()
    .Where(x => x.Name == "Jamie")
    .Inner.JoinQueryOver(t => t.Posts, () => posts)
    .List();
```

As you might have noticed using Fetch Eager:

```
var users = session.QueryOver<User>()
    .Where(x => x.Name == "Jamie")
    .Fetch(x=>x.Posts).Eager
    .List();
```

uses an outer join which you do not want.

The previous two examples will have a problem you've mentioned in your comment.
If you want to avoid cartesian products in your result with QueryOver you can use `.TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)` :

```
Post posts = null;

var users = session.QueryOver<User>()
    .Where(x => x.Name == "Jamie")
    .Inner.JoinAlias(t => t.Posts, () => posts)
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
    .List();
```

You can find lot more information [here](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx).

Comment: using `Inner` seems like a good direction, and the generated SQL is indeed what I was looking for. but the problem is that the `Posts` collection isn't initialized. meaning- after calling the code in your example, `NHibernateUtil.IsInitialized(user.Posts)` evaluated to `false`. even if I add `.Fetch(x=>x.Posts).Eager
` to the query. any idea why is that?

Comment: @sJhonny: I've tried NHibernateUtil.IsInitialized on my sample code and it works properly. Could you post some code/hbm?

Comment: yep, you're right. my problem was that I had a collection of abstract types. I've asked another, more challenging question about it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024348/fetching-strategies-for-collections-of-abstract-type

Comment: @sJhonny: I'll have a look at your question as soon as I've got a little bit of time.