# How to fetch top 20 of parent entities with all children for each entity

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, fetch, eager-loading

I have an aggregate root which is a WallPost. A WallPost can have zero to many WallPostComments.

I wish to write a query to fetch 20 wall posts (ordered by DateCreated descending) and also eagerly fetch all comments for these 20 wall posts.

I have tried using NHibernate Linq and the Fetch() clause but this results in "firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory!" error.

Two other approaches I've tried are:

```
var wallPostQuery = _session.QueryOver<WallPost>()
            .Where(x => x.WallId == wallId)
            .OrderBy(x => x.DateCreated)
            .Desc
            .Left.JoinQueryOver(x => x.Comments)
            .Take(20)
            .Future<WallPost>();
```

But, surprise surprise (well, not really) this brings back twenty wall posts with zero or one comment each. I get duplicate wall posts, which is not what I want.

A better query is

```
var wallPostQuery = _session.QueryOver<WallPost>().Where(x => x.WallId == wallId).OrderBy(x => x.DateCreated).Desc.Take(20).Future<WallPost>();

_session.QueryOver<WallPost>().Where(x => x.WallId == wallId).Left.JoinQueryOver(x => x.Comments).Future<WallPost>();

var wallPosts = wallPostQuery.ToList();
```

This gives me 20 wall posts with their associated comments, but the query is executed as two selects where the second select joins WallPost to WallPostComment, effectively pulling back *all* wall posts and comments (filtered only by the WallPostId). This works fine while there are small numbers of posts - but I can't imagine this scaling very well.

There must be a better way - but I can't seem to figure it out. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024348/fetching-strategies-for-collections-of-abstract-type/7349631#7349631) i've found to a similar (a little more complex) problem may help you.
something along the lines of:

```
var wallPostIdsQuery = _session.QueryOver<WallPost>().Where(x => x.WallId == wallId).OrderBy(x => x.DateCreated).Desc.Take(20).Future<WallPost>()
.Select(p => p.Id);

var wallPostsQuery = _session.QueryOver<WallPost>().WithSubquery.WhereProperty(p => p.Id).In(wallPostIdsQuery);

var commentsQuery = _session.QueryOver<WallPostComment>().WithSubquery.WhereProperty(p => p.WallPostId).In(wallPostIdsQuery);

if (wallPostsQuery.Count() == 0)
{
  return wallPostsQuery.List();
}

NHibernateUtil.Initialize(wallPostsQuery.First().Comments);
```

or, possibly, just those two lines-

```
var wallPostQuery = _session.QueryOver<WallPost>().Where(x => x.WallId == wallId).OrderBy(x => x.DateCreated).Desc.Take(20).Future<WallPost>();
NHibernateUtil.Initialize(wallPostQuery.First().Comments);
```

the important thing to remember is to map the comments collection with the 'subselect' fetching strategy.

Comment: thanks for your help. This works (I've used the shorter version of your suggestion) and although NHibernate Profiler complains of SELECT N+1 (because NHibernateUtil.Initialize does 10 subsequent selects) I am happier with this than my own solution. Now - I notice that the SELECT statements generated to fetch comments fetch these for two posts at a time: WHERE  comments0_.WallPost_id in (193, 192).  Is there a way to fetch them all at once?

Comment: this seems very strange; is the comments collection mapped with subselect strategy?

Comment: Hmmm... no, all I've got is this: var wallPostQuery = _session.QueryOver<WallPost>().Where(x => x.WallId == wallId).OrderBy(x => x.DateCreated).Desc.Take(20).Future<WallPost>();
            NHibernateUtil.Initialize(wallPostQuery.First().Comments);

Comment: and the fetching strategy in the mappings?

Comment: Haha! It was set to batched, with a size of "2". D'oh! I've changed it to subselect and everything works perfectly. Thank you very much for your help!